# Get error output from Python script called from Java

Tags: java, python-3.x, runtime.exec

I have some Java code that calls a Python script:

```
String[] cmd = new String[]{"python", "path/to/script", "arg1", "arg2"}
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec(cmd);
```

As long as the Python script contains no errors it works fine, but as soon as it does it breaks. However, I don't get the error message that I would get if I would run the Python script directly from the command line, so I have to search myself what went wrong where. Not very efficient.

Is it possible to get this message by adding some lines to my Java code?

Comment: This solved my problem: `proc.getErrorStream()` was what I was looking for. If you write your comment as an answer I can accept it. (And the error that broke the script and that I just couldn't find: I forgot a colon after an `elif`...)

Comment: *"I forgot a colon after an `elif`...)"* Those kinds of errors plague us all. It's a good thing there is error output to be had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [When `Runtime.exec()` won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.

Now to the specifics of the problem at hand, it sounds like it is the output from the error stream that is missing. As you noted, calling `proc.getErrorStream()` and processing that output should fit the requirement.